# Javascript is posting variables but all my data is not input into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL database that I am adding records to through a form using AJAX. Console is telling me that all my data is being posted to the php page, and I'm not getting any error. However, not all the data is showing up in the database.

PHP:

```
    //set values sent from javascript
        $evaluator = $_SESSION['id'];
        $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
        $student_work = $_POST['student_work'];
        $student = $_POST['student'];
        $assessment = $_POST['assessment'];
        $classwork = $_POST['classwork'];
        $best = $_POST['best'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $binder = $_POST['binder'];
        $teacherid = $_POST['teacher'];
        $formid = $_POST['form'];
        $draft_flag = $_POST['s'];
        //set draft time to use for saving/updating drafts
        $draft_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        //flag that decided what we're saving, ie draft, submit, update.
        $flag =   $_POST['draft'];
        //Querys the database to get the form name
        $fquery = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT form_name FROM forms WHERE id_form='$formid' LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fquery);
        $form_name  = $row['form_name'];
        //query's the database to get the teacher's school for this evaluation
        $tquery = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT id_school FROM teachers WHERE teacher_id='$teacherid' LIMIT 1");
        $trow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tquery);
        $id_school = $trow['id_school'];

        include_once 'functions/functions.php';

if ($draft_flag == "submit"){

//inserts collected data and sets status as submitted in the evaluations table
$query = "INSERT INTO evaluations SET 
        id_user = '$evaluator',
        time_submitted = LOCALTIME(),
        date_submitted = NOW(),
        feedback = '$feedback', 
        student_work_org = '$student_work',
        best_works_port = '$best',
        binder = '$binder',
        assesment_folders = '$assessment',
        classwork_organization = '$classwork',
        student_desks = '$student',
        subject_specific_rubric = '$subject',
        id_teacher = '$teacherid',
        id_school = '$id_school',
        id_form = '$formid',
        status = 'Submitted'";

mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query); 
?>
```

Out of all the variables, these are not posting:

```
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
$student_work = $_POST['student_work'];
$student = $_POST['student'];
$assessment = $_POST['assessment'];
$classwork = $_POST['classwork'];
$best = $_POST['best']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$binder = $_POST['binder'];
```

That's 8 of the 12 not posting.

EDIT: Here is what is sent by the js:

```
ajax.send(
            "classwork=" + classwork
            + "&student_work=" + student_work
            + "&feedback=" + feedback
            + "&assessment=" + assessment
            + "&best=" + best
            + "&student=" + student
            + "&subject=" + subject
            + "&binder=" + binder
            + "&teacher=" + teacher
            + "&form=" + form
            + "&draft=" + draft
            + "&s=" + s
            );
```

I have several other forms just like this that are working fine. Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:

Please do not tell me my syntax is incorrect, unless you're going to tell me I missed a comma or something. (which I checked for, so I doubt that's the problem :) ) I know it may not be the way YOU would INSERT, but it's correct according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Just tried and it did the same thing.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO evaluations (
        id_user, 
        time_submitted, 
        date_submitted, 
        feedback,  
        student_work_org, 
        best_works_port, 
        binder, '$binder',
        assesment_folders, 
        classwork_organization, 
        student_desks, 
        subject_specific_rubric, 
        id_teacher, 
        id_school, 
        id_form, 
        status) 
VALUES (
        '$evaluator',
        LOCALTIME(),
        NOW(),
        '$feedback',
        '$student_work',
        '$best',
        '$assessment',
        '$subject',
        '$classwork',
        '$student',
        '$teacherid',
        '$id_school',
        '$formid',
        'Submitted'
) ";
```

Comment: What does it mean "not all the data is showing up in the database"? Sometimes the row is inserted, sometimes not? Or, the row is inserted with some columns having a wrong value? Or their default value (or NULL?) instead of what was expected?

Comment: The row is always inserted, but 8 of the 12 variables that are supposed to be posted are Null.

Comment: I don't think the probem is with the insert code. Probably the data, although I'd expect it to return an error. The values that are posting look to be numeric, the ones that are failing are text, is it possibly an encoding issue and then MySQL extension you are using is suppressing errors -(I never use PHP so am not familiar with the exact structure you're using, is it possibly actually processing an INSERT IGNORE query?) OR, is it a database structure issue?

Comment: From what I see, there seems to have great chances that the problem is *not* at SQL-level. Please could you `print_r($_POST)` in order to check is the various post parameters are set as one might expect it...

Comment: @Sylvain leroux I'll try `print_r` and get back to you, thanks! @Jamie Hartnoll that's a good point, although `status` is text, not numerical.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but it is working now. Maybe the old php was cached or something. (I thought I cleared it, but I may not have.)

Answer (score 1):

Your [INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) is wrong. This is the correct form:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> (
    <field name foo>
    <field name bar>
    .
    .
    .
)
VALUES (
    <value for foo>,
    <value for bar>,
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the syntax I'm using is the MySQL extension syntax, it works fine in the other 30 form submits that I'm using, and it submits part of this form just fine as well.